# Custom date selector in android

Tags: android, datepicker

I want to implement date selector like this in my app but I don't know how to do it I have searched a lot but couldn't find any solution
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjpQK.png)

I tried different libraries but can not achieve the exact output

Comment: does it will scroll future dates till how much ??

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: yes it will scroll for for dates of whole year for example if today is 19 december it will scroll till  next 18 december